# What is wrong with do while of this code

Tags: php

I have written following code but its not executing. Kindly let me know what I did wrong. I double checked it and didnot find any errors my self so far.

**ERROR:**

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in E:\test.php on line 5*

```
<ul>
    <?php $x=1; do { ?>
    <li><a href="#tab<?php echo $x; ?>" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>       
    <? $x++; } while ($x < 10) ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I copy and tried it doesn't given any error to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely case is that you do not have `short tags` enabled, meaning the last `<? $x++ }...` bit isn't being read as PHP. Consequently, the `}` is not found, and the PHP script is still looking for it when the end is reached. Therefore, unexpected end.

Here is your code, rewritten to be readable:

```
<?php
for( $x=1; $x<10; $x++) {
    echo '<li><a href="#tab'.$x.'" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, You have used shorttags `<?` changed into `<?php`

```
                <?php $x=1; do { ?>
                    <li><a href="#tab<?php echo $x; ?>" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
                <?php $x++; } while ($x < 10); ?>
```

Tells PHP whether the short form (`<? ?>`) of PHP's open tag should be allowed. If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can disable this option in order to use  inline. Otherwise, you can print it with PHP, for example: `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>`. Also, if disabled, you must use the long form of the PHP open tag (`<?php ?>`).

**Note:** This directive also affected the shorthand `<?=` before PHP 5.4.0, which is identical to `<? echo`. Use of this shortcut required **short_open_tag** to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

Comment: Explain what you changed, why you changed it, and why what you posted should work where OP's failed.

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped `<?php` with `<?`

**Try This :**

```
<?php $x=1; do { ?>
<li><a href="#tab<?php echo $x; ?>" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
<?php $x++; } while ($x < 10) ?>
```

**Or**

```
<?php 
$x=1;
do { 
echo '<li><a href="#tab'.$x.'" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>';
$x++; } while ($x < 10); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In most php configurations, writing `<?php`
is usually better than 
     `<?`.
using `<?` causes some errors when you execute the script..